# How to force nodejs winston log to file before process exit

Tags: node.js, winston

I am using [winston 3](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) to log my data. But sometimes it didn't log the error before process exit.

The following process will exit, without log to the `logfile.log`:

```js
const winston = require('winston');

winston.add(new winston.transports.File({
    filename: 'logfile.log'
}));

winston.info('please log me in');
process.exit(1);
```

One of attempted solution is used callback:

```js
const winston = require('winston');

const logger = new winston.createLogger({
    new winston.transports.File({
    filename: 'logfile.log'
}));

winston.info('please log me in', () => {
    process.exit(1);
});

setTimeout(() => {}, 100000000000); // pause the process until process.exit is call
```

But Winston 3.x have [callback issue](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1250), so the above code won't work, the process will not exit.

I am looking for a workable solution? Any help will be greatly appreciated. My OS is **Ubuntu 16.04**, **Node 10.17**.

**Edit 1:**
I also have try `Prabhjot Singh Kainth`'s suggestion use `finish` event to trigger process exit:

```js
const winston = require('winston');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({
            filename: 'logfile.log'
        })
    ]
});

logger.info('please log me in');

logger.on('finish', () => {
    process.exit();
});
logger.end();

setTimeout(() => {}, 100000000000); // pause the process until process.exit is call
```

In the above case, the process will exit, but no log file will be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I find a workable solution. Instead of listening to `logger` `finish` event, it should listen to `file._dest` `finish` event. But `file._dest` is only created after `file` `open` event. So it need to wait for `file` `open` event in initialization process.

```js
const winston = require('winston');

const file = new winston.transports.File({
  filename: 'logfile.log'
});

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [file]
});

file.on('open', () => {  // wait until file._dest is ready
  logger.info('please log me in');
  logger.error('logging error message');
  logger.warn('logging warning message');

  file._dest.on('finish', () => {
    process.exit();
  });
  logger.end();
});

setTimeout(() => {}, 100000000000); // pause the process until process.exit is call
```

Comment: The problem with this situation is the process will exit on that 'file' transport, but what if you have '2' file transports?

Answer (score 3):

How about this one?

```
logger.info('First message...')
logger.info('Last message', () => process.exit(1))
```

Comment: No possible under winston 3.x.x, loggers no longer take a callback.

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of winston.Logger is also a Node.js stream.

A finish event will be raised when all logs have flushed to all transports after the stream has been ended.

Just try using this code :

```
const transport = new winston.transports.Console();
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [transport]
});
logger.on('finish', function (info) {
  // All `info` log messages has now been logged
});

logger.info('CHILL WINSTON!', { seriously: true });
logger.end();
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I am trying to write to a file not console. Console transports is always works fine. But if you use `winston.transports.File({filename:'log'})`, the log file will not create when process exit.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer from @WanChap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59260151/3025856) was good, but not when there is **multiple file transports**. I will post my entire logging solution below, which handles exiting the process correctly, including support for Development and Production.

The *only* caveat is that it does not work with the exceptions log at the moment, but it will work with every other transport based log. If anyone figures out how to make this work with the exception log as well, please post in the comments.

First, you want to create a folder in the same directory that your file that is doing the logs is in, and call it `logger`. In this folder, create three `.js` files, one called **`dev-logger.js`**, the other **`prod-logger.js`**, and finally **`index.js`**

In node, when you require a directory, it will assume you want to load the **`index.js` file.**

**`TheFileYouWantToLogFrom.js`**

```
const logger = require('./logger');
logger.info("it works!");
```

**`index.js`**

This file will look at your node process environment state and use the correct logger.

```
const buildDevLogger = require('./dev-logger');
const buildProdLogger = require('./prod-logger');

let logger = null;
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
    logger = buildDevLogger();
}else{
    logger = buildProdLogger();
}

module.exports = logger;
```

You can test this later, by simply calling your node process (in my case cron.js) in your terminal, by saying something like `NODE_ENV=production node cron.js` or `NODE_ENV=development node cron.js`

**`dev-logger.js`**

```
const { format, createLogger, transports} = require('winston');
const { timestamp, combine, printf, errors } = format;

var numOpenTransports = 0;

function buildDevLogger(){
    const logFormat = printf(({ level, message, timestamp, stack, durationMs }) => {
        return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${stack || message}${durationMs ? " | "+durationMs+'ms' : ''}`;
    });
    
    //For info on the options go here.
    //https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md
    var options = {
        console: {
            handleExceptions: true,
            level: 'debug',
            format: combine(
                format.colorize(),
                timestamp({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'}),
                errors({stack: true}),
                logFormat
            ),
        },
        combined: {
            filename: 'logs/dev/combined.log',
            maxsize: 10000000,
            maxFiles: 10,
            tailable:true,
            format: combine(
                timestamp({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'}),
                errors({stack: true}),
                logFormat
            ),
        },
        error: { 
            filename: 'logs/dev/error.log',
            level: 'error',
            maxsize: 10000000,
            maxFiles: 10,
            tailable:true ,
            format: combine(
                timestamp({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'}),
                errors({stack: true}),
                logFormat
            ),
        },
        exception : {
            filename: 'logs/dev/exceptions.log',
            maxsize: 10000000,
            maxFiles: 10,
            tailable:true,
            format: combine(
                timestamp({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'}),
                errors({stack: true}),
                logFormat
            ),
        }
    };

    function fileFinished(){
        numOpenTransports--;
        if(numOpenTransports==0){
            process.exit(0);
        }
    }

    var combinedFile = new transports.File(options.combined);
    var errorFile = new transports.File(options.error);
    var exceptionFile = new transports.File(options.exception);

    combinedFile.on('open', () => {  // wait until file._dest is ready
        numOpenTransports++;
        combinedFile._dest.on('finish', () => {
            fileFinished();
        });
    });
    errorFile.on('open', () => {  // wait until file._dest is ready
        numOpenTransports++;
        errorFile._dest.on('finish', () => {
            fileFinished();
        });
    });

    return createLogger({
        defaultMeta: {service:'cron-dev'},
        transports: [
            new transports.Console(options.console),
            combinedFile, 
            errorFile,
        ],
        exceptionHandlers: [
            exceptionFile
        ]
    });
}

module.exports = buildDevLogger;
```

**`prod-logger.js`**

```
const { format, createLogger, transports} = require('winston');
const { timestamp, combine, errors, json } = format;

var numOpenTransports = 0;

function buildProdLogger(){
    var options = {
        console: {
            handleExceptions: true,
            level: 'debug',
            format: combine(
                timestamp({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'}),
                errors({stack: true}),
                json()
            ),
        },
        combined: {
            filename: 'logs/prod/combined.log',
            maxsize: 10000000,
            maxFiles: 10,
            tailable:true,
            format: combine(
                timestamp({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'}),
                errors({stack: true}),
                json()
            ),
        },
        error: { 
            filename: 'logs/prod/error.log',
            level: 'error',
            maxsize: 10000000,
            maxFiles: 10,
            tailable:true ,
            format: combine(
                timestamp({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'}),
                errors({stack: true}),
                json()
            ),
        },
        exception : {
            filename: 'logs/prod/exceptions.log',
            maxsize: 10000000,
            maxFiles: 10,
            tailable:true,
            format: combine(
                timestamp({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'}),
                errors({stack: true}),
                json()
            ),
        }  
    };

    function fileFinished(){
        numOpenTransports--;
        if(numOpenTransports==0){
            process.exit(0);
        }
    }

    var combinedFile = new transports.File(options.combined);
    var errorFile = new transports.File(options.error);
    var exceptionFile = new transports.File(options.exception);

    combinedFile.on('open', () => {  // wait until file._dest is ready
        numOpenTransports++;
        combinedFile._dest.on('finish', () => {
            fileFinished();
        });
    });
    errorFile.on('open', () => {  // wait until file._dest is ready
        numOpenTransports++;
        errorFile._dest.on('finish', () => {
            fileFinished();
        });
    });

    return createLogger({
        defaultMeta: {service:'cron-prod'},
        transports: [
            new transports.Console(options.console),
            combinedFile, 
            errorFile,
        ],
        exceptionHandlers: [
            exceptionFile
        ]
    });
}

module.exports = buildProdLogger;
```

The way the dev and prod logger files work is by using the `numOpenTransports` variable to keep track of which 'files transports' are currently open, and once they are all closed, *then*, and *only* then, **exit the process**.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code, but I always got "TypeError: file.on is not a function". I'm using winston version 3.9.0.

```
const winston = require('winston');

const file = new winston.transports.File({
  filename: 'logfile.log'
});

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [file]
});

file.on('open', () => {  // wait until file._dest is ready
  logger.info('please log me in');
  logger.error('logging error message');
  logger.warn('logging warning message');

  file._dest.on('finish', () => {
    process.exit();
  });
  logger.end();
});

setTimeout(() => {}, 100000000000); // pause the process until process.exit is call
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34570088)